# How to check if address in within region on Google Maps API

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, region

I have an address string E.g. "12 Swiss Ave, Gonville, Wanganui, New Zealand"

Given this address I need to work out if the address is within the North or South island of New Zealand.

If I pass the address to the google maps api the data I get back is below, unfortunately though it doesn't tell me what island it is in. So, how can I check this?

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "12",
                    "short_name": "12",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Swiss Avenue",
                    "short_name": "Swiss Ave",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Gonville",
                    "short_name": "Gonville",
                    "types": [
                        "sublocality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Wanganui",
                    "short_name": "Wanganui",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Manawatu-Wanganui",
                    "short_name": "Manawatu-Wanganui",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New Zealand",
                    "short_name": "NZ",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "4501",
                    "short_name": "4501",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "12 Swiss Avenue, Gonville, Wanganui 4501, New Zealand",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": -39.9444245,
                    "lng": 175.0239575
                },
                "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": -39.9430755197085,
                        "lng": 175.0253064802915
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": -39.9457734802915,
                        "lng": 175.0226085197085
                    }
                }
            },
            "types": [
                "street_address"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to get the polygons for the two islands and do point in polygon analysis on the geographic location.

[Example using Polygons defined by KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html) and [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

[Proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygonKmz_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/NZL_adm0_separateNSIslands.kmz) (using geoxml3 and modified KML from gadm.org)

============ older option using fusion tables, no longer works =============

[Example using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html) (**note:** no longer works, Fusion Layers was turned down December 2019)

[Proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_NewZealand.html) (using the Natural Earth data set in Fusion Tables and a "state to island" map) (**note:** also no longer works)

Answer (score 0):

Well using Google Map's API..

You can get the placeId of the north island of NZ from say [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete), which is `ChIJhXgO3F4Uam0RdyMcnMutKMo`

Then use the geocode library to get the bounds, and use the [contains function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds-Methods) to test if another lat/lng are in these bounds.

```
const geocode = async placeId => {
  const geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    geocoder.geocode(
      {
        placeId
      },
      (results, status) => {
        resolve(results[0]);
      }
    );
  });
};

const placeDetails = await geocode('ChIJhXgO3F4Uam0RdyMcnMutKMo');
const somePlace = getPlaceDetails(someOtherPlaceId);

const isInNorthIsland = placeDetails.geometry.bounds.contains(somePlace.geometry.location);
```